# Error Code 1241

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't understand what is wrong with my code and why this error keeps popping up

```
CREATE VIEW LocUserComp AS
SELECT concat(location.Loc_Address, location.Loc_City, 
       location.Loc_State) AS Customer_Address, 
      (users.User_FName, users.User_LName) AS Customer_Name
FROM location
JOIN users
ON location.Loc_ID=Users.Loc_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the parentheses around the two columns.  I think you intend for a second `concat()`:

```
CREATE VIEW LocUserComp AS
    SELECT concat(l.Loc_Address, l.Loc_City, l.Loc_State) AS Customer_Address, 
           concat(u.User_FName, u.User_LName) AS Customer_Name
    FROM location l JOIN
         users u
         ON l.Loc_ID = u.Loc_ID;
```